# cannot set State in functional component while fetching data from Firebase in reactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, dictionary, state

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log("mounted");
all.db.ref("NewDonor").on("child_added", (data) => {
  var DataFromDB = data.val();
  state.donor.push(DataFromDB);
  console.log(state.donor);
  setState({
    donor: DataFromDB,
  });
});
```

}, [0]);

Here is some of my code.. i want to fetch data from firebase and add into my state and render on DOM,
but cannot be able to set state..it's showing an error,
state.donor.map is not a function

Comment: That isn't exactly how the state work in a functional component.
Look for the `useState` hook :)

Comment: setState is for class-based components, Did you define your state using useState hook?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your state is an array

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ donor: [] });
```

Then this is how you would update it. Spread any existing state into a new array, and then also spread in the new data from the DB. This ensures that `state.donor` remains an array for mapping later. I also don't think `[0]` is a valid dependency array, seems you want to only trigger effect when the component mounts so an empty dependency array works.

```
useEffect(() => {
  all.db.ref("NewDonor").on("child_added", (data) => {
    const DataFromDB = data.val();
    setState(prevState => ({
      donor: [...prevState, ...DataFromDB],
    }));
  });
}, []);
```